# Which one in best for string encryption jasypt and bcrypt?

Tags: java, encryption, bcrypt, jasypt

I want to encrypt passwords in my application. So any one can suggest me which is best for strong password encryption whether jasypt or bcrypt

Best,
Sureshram

Comment: Bcrypt is not used for encryption. It's an computationally expensive hash function. So the answer would be jasypt, but I don't recommend it. It has bad defaults.

Comment: Also, *"best"* under what constraints? There is no best anything in the world. There is always something that is good enough for a specific use case under specific conditions. There is also not such thing as good and bad in the world. There are only competing interest.

Comment: Maybe it's better not to store passwords and to think about other solutions. Encrypted or not doesn't matter when the encrypted password is stored on a location which you don't control. If the encrypted password will be stored for example inside the application Jar file, then the decryption code would be also in that Jar. Someone having access to the Jar could then decrypt the password as well.

Comment: I misread your question. Of course, your users' passwords should never be encrypted. It may be necessary if you are a trusted third party that holds the passwords to authenticate against another server of the user. You should clarify what this is for.